# error creating bean with name 'accountController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'accountService

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I looked up some similar questions, but those answers couldn't help me.

**error**

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'accountService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.service.AccountService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

**AccountController**

```
package com.controller;
import com.domain.Account;
import com.service.AccountService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save",produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public String save(Account account){
        accountService.save(account);
        return "save success";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/findAll")
    public ModelAndView findAll(){
        List<Account> accountList = accountService.findAll();
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("accountList",accountList);
        modelAndView.setViewName("accountList");
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

**AccountServiceImpl**

```
package com.service.impl;

import com.domain.Account;
import com.mapper.AccountMapper;
import com.service.AccountService;
import org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

@Service("accountService")
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountMapper accountMapper;

    @Override
    public void save(Account account) {
        accountMapper.save(account);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Account> findAll() {
        return accountMapper.findAll();
    }
}
```

**AcountService**

```
package com.service;

import com.domain.Account;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public interface AccountService {

    public void save(Account account);

    public List<Account> findAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `com.service` is not being scanned in your @SpringBootApplication setup.

Comment: Depends on how you are configuring the application. Can you add if you are defining these beans if an xml or annotation the main method?